# are pokerstars.net hand histories saved?

Tags: poker-stars, pokertracker

I have been playing some home games recently on the pokerstars.net client that is available for US players. The client uses only play money and I am having trouble finding where (if at all) the hand histories are saved. Has anyone else used this software before in the US? if so, were you able to save your hand histories at the play money tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from what I've seen from Pokerstars help center, it looks like for pokerstars.net the answer is no.

https://www.pokerstars.com/help/articles/hh-pm-older-7-days/11133/

Comment: thanks, i have trouble reaching pokerstars articles so thats very helpful